# How to not create a function every time for the handler if there can be multiple of them?

Tags: reactjs

For example, it is a StarRating component that can let the user select 1 to 5 stars or 1 to 10 stars, and the component is:

```
export default function StarRating({ numStars = 5 }) {
  const [numSelectedStars, setNumSelectedStars] = useState(0);

  return Array.from({ length: numStars }).map((e, i) =>
    <Star
      key={i}
      selected={i < numSelectedStars}
      handleSelect={() => setNumSelectedStars(i + 1)}
    />
  );
}
```

If there are 10 stars maximum, then there can be 10 anonymous functions created every time `StarRating` is re-rendered.  Is there a way to

1. somehow cache the functions
2. use a different method

to prevent the excessive function creation?

It seems it might be able to be done by `useCallback(fn, deps)`, but since the number of stars is dynamic, so it can be 5 or 10 such functions. Also, isn't it a rule that you have to list useCallback() line by line, but can't put them in a loop to create 10 of them?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to just remove `handleSelect={() => setNumSelectedStars(i + 1)}`. I'm right??

Comment: you shouldn't bother with this. Modern compilers are quite advanced, you will not gain any preformance benefits out of this, but code readability will suffer

Comment: @hrghafoori it does look like it might be able to be done by `React.useCallback(fn, deps)`, but since the number of stars is dynamic, so it can be 5 or 10 such functions. Also, isn't it a rule that you have to list `useCallback()` line by line, but can't put them in a loop to create 10 of them?

Comment: @Max you mean they just get garbage collected, and 10 such small functions are close to nothing? (maybe a few kb or less?)

Comment: @deeper-understanding yes, and not only because of memory, the processing cost of creating these functions is microscopic. It's just a function that calls another function with value taken from outer scope. The only way to avoid creating them would be passing `i` and `setNumSelectedStars` to `Star` and calling it inside `Star`, which you don't want to do because it's not `Star`'s responsibility to handle clicks. And creating intermediate component between `StarRating` and `Star` just to contain handle logic is more taxing on performance than having `handleSelect` functions recreated each time